# How to add a user library to Eclipse project using Gradle?

Tags: gradle

Is it possible to add a custom user library with a set of JARs using Gradle to an eclipse project? If so, how do I go about it?

Comment: If the user library already exist (Selenium is the custom user library here), you can add it to your project using the following code 
`eclipse {
    classpath {
        containers  'org.eclipse.jdt.USER_LIBRARY/Selenium'
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

The validity of this answer can be found [here](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/gradle-eclipse-classpath-containers/6990/8).

```
eclipse.classpath {
    containers 'org.eclipse.jdt.USER_LIBRARY/my.container'
}
```

Following the placement of this code in the build file, you would then have to run the `eclipseClasspath` task order for the changes to take effect in your project.